# Openzeppalin Governance wizard reuturns "ProviderError: max code size exceeded"

Tags: contract-deployment, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, dao, governance

## openzeppalin wizard Governance error

i am using the copy and pasted code from openzeppalin for there governance smartcontract but returns error

### smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/Governor.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorSettings.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorCountingSimple.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotes.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorVotesQuorumFraction.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/governance/extensions/GovernorTimelockControl.sol";

contract Governance is Governor, GovernorSettings, GovernorCountingSimple, GovernorVotes, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction, GovernorTimelockControl {
    constructor(IVotes _token, TimelockController _timelock)
        Governor("Governance")
        GovernorSettings(7200 /* 1 day */, 50400 /* 1 week */, 200000e18)
        GovernorVotes(_token)
        GovernorVotesQuorumFraction(4)
        GovernorTimelockControl(_timelock)
    {}

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function votingDelay()
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingDelay();
    }

    function votingPeriod()
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.votingPeriod();
    }

    function quorum(uint256 blockNumber)
        public
        view
        override(IGovernor, GovernorVotesQuorumFraction)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.quorum(blockNumber);
    }

    function state(uint256 proposalId)
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (ProposalState)
    {
        return super.state(proposalId);
    }

    function propose(address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, string memory description)
        public
        override(Governor, IGovernor)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.propose(targets, values, calldatas, description);
    }

    function proposalThreshold()
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorSettings)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super.proposalThreshold();
    }

    function _execute(uint256 proposalId, address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
    {
        super._execute(proposalId, targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _cancel(address[] memory targets, uint256[] memory values, bytes[] memory calldatas, bytes32 descriptionHash)
        internal
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        return super._cancel(targets, values, calldatas, descriptionHash);
    }

    function _executor()
        internal
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (address)
    {
        return super._executor();
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(Governor, GovernorTimelockControl)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

### error

```
ProviderError: max code size exceeded
    at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\Documents\programming\smartcontract\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:88:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\Users\Documents\programming\smartcontract\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

### Things i tried

i tried to reduce the code size by using the simplified version of there governance smartcontract
i also changed my hardhat config and made optimizer run 200 i also tried 1000